# How to display linked list after adding elements to it

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on a school project that works with linked lists, and it's basically a program that adds various elements to a linked list with an "add" command, shows what I added, and then displays it with a "disp" command.

The shell is already implemented and I don't have access to its source code, meaning that I cannot modify the function prototypes. Now, when I try to call "disp" within the "add" function, the elements get displayed correctly, but when I call it outside "add" it instantly segfaults with no output. Valgrind just gives me an "invalid read of size 1" but I can't make sense of it.

Here's my code, with each block being a separate file.

```
typedef struct linked_list_s {
    char *hardware;
    int nb;
    char *type;
    struct linked_list_s *next;
} linked_list_t;
```

```
void push_to_list(linked_list_t **begin, char *type, int nb, char *hardware)
{
    linked_list_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_t));

    new_node->type = type;
    new_node->nb = nb;
    new_node->hardware = hardware;
    new_node->next = *begin;
    *begin = new_node;
}
```

```
int add(void *data, char **args)
{
    static int nb = 0;

    for (int i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i += 2) {
        linked_list_t *entity = NULL;
        push_to_list((linked_list_t **)&data, args[i], nb, args[i + 1]);
        entity = data;
        if (entity->next != NULL) {
            my_printf("%s n°%d - \"%s\" added.\n", (char *)entity->type, entit\
y->nb, (char *)entity->hardware);
            entity = entity->next;
        }
        nb++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int del(void *data, char **args)
{
    return 0;
}

int sort(void *data, char **args)
{
    return 0;
}
int disp(void *data, char **args)
{
    linked_list_t *current = (linked_list_t *)data;
    while (current != NULL) {
        my_printf("%s n°%d - \"%s\"\n", (char *)current->type, current->nb, (c\
har *)current->hardware);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    static linked_list_t *data = NULL;

    workshop_shell((void *)&data);
    return 0;
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
./organized
Workshop » add WIRE usb, ACTUATOR button, DEVICE recorder
WIRE n°0 - “usb” added.
ACTUATOR n°1 - “button” added.
DEVICE n°2 - “recorder” added. 
## the above works
Workshop » disp
DEVICE n°2 - “recorder”
ACTUATOR n°1 - “button”
WIRE n°0 - “usb”
## here, instead of showing the list, my program instantly segfaults
```

I tried initializing the link listed globally, with the same results.

Note that this is my first time working with linked lists, and that I'm a beginner, so if it's completely off, please explain me why and how it's wrong.

Comment: Could you add some stdout/stderr output, so as to narrow down the exact line that produces the segfault?

Comment: I assume this is C. I have tagged it - it may have missed a lot of attention due to it not having a language tag.

Comment: If you are still in need of an answer let me know here (`@halfer`) and I will add a bounty to it.

Comment: Look at the **types** of things being passed as argument. It is unclear what they are, exactly (this homework looks poorly-designed, alas). It appears that `data`, while passed as a simple `void*`, is actually a `linked_list_t **`. Notice how your `add()` function does not update the value of `*data`.

Comment: I tried to copy in the source code and compile the code.  I ended up with errors referencing missing functions (my_printf and workshop_shell).  You need to provide a minimal executable example to allow others to evaluate your issue.